# Why can't I set properties of an array element (a string) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
array[0].property = 'value';

alert(array[0].property);   
alert(array[0].property = 'value');
alert(array[0].property);
```

The result? `undefined`, `'value'`, then `undefined`

Why isn't this code working as expected?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Array is irrelevant - you're trying to set a property on a [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JS/Glossary):

> A data that is not an **object** and does
>   not have any methods. JavaScript has 5
>   primitive **datatypes**: **string**, **number**,
>   **boolean**, **null**, **undefined**. With the
>   exception of null and undefined, all
>   primitives values have object
>   equivalents which **wrap** around the
>   primitive values, e.g. a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JS/String) object
>   wraps around a string primitive. All
>   primitives are **immutable**.

If you absolutely must use a property to carry this additional information around in a string, an alternative would be to use the object equivalent:

```
>>> var array = [new String('a'), new String('b'), new String('c')];
>>> array[0].property
undefined
>>> array[0].property = 'value'
"value"
>>> array[0].property
"value"
```

A potential gotcha to look out for if you do this and later need to detect that the value is a string:

```
>>> var a = ['s', new String('s')];
>>> a.map(function(s) { return typeof s; });
["string", "object"]
>>> a.map(function(s) { return s instanceof String });
[false, true]
>>> a.map(function(s) { return Object.prototype.toString.call(s) == '[object String]' });
[true, true]
```

Comment: another gotcha: `[new String('a')].indexOf('a') === -1`

Answer (score 3):

Your array elements are string *literals*. JavaScript makes it seem like string literals are objects and have properties, but what's actually happening when you do `array[0].property` is that JavaScript is creating a temporary object for your string and assigning the property to that.

That's why the middle alert works correctly and the others don't. If you declared your array like:

```
var array = [new String('a'), new String('b'), new String('c')];
```

all three would work.

Answer (score 2):

`array[0]` is a string, namely `'a'` which you set in the first line and in JavaScript strings can't have additional properties.

If you want to use properties you have to use an object, for example a simple "empty" object: `new Object()` or short `{}`:

```
var array = [{}];
array[0].property = 'value';

alert(array[0].property);   
alert(array[0].property = 'value');
alert(array[0].property);
```

Comment: Crap. I never knew that. It appears that numbers can't have additional properties, either. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a quirk (or performance restriction) in JavaScript -- the *primitive* types `string`, `boolean`, and `number` are *immutable* and any property assignment will just "vanish" (the single-inhabitant primitive types `undefined` and `null` will throw an exception on attempted property assignment). This is because these primitive values are *not* real objects (it makes them much more lightweight for the run-time).

*However,* for each of the primitive types there is a wrapper type: `String`, `Boolean`, and `Number`, respectively. The wrapper types are *real* objects and can have custom properties assigned.

While *I would not do this*, this will work (it sounds like an "icky design"):

```
var s = new String("foo");
s.bar = "hello"
alert(s.bar)
```

However, there are a number of odd quirks that this introduces -- `typeof ""` is "string" while `typeof s` is "object"*, and `"" instanceof String` is false while `s instanceof String` is true. Also, `new Boolean(false)` happens to be a truth-y value.

Happy coding.

---

*This will break a number of noddy library that do `typeof x === "string"`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do `'a'.property = 'something'`.

I'm not aware of any language that lets you assign a property of a string;

that would be like doing `12.property = 'something'`.

Comment: You can, however, assign a property to the *prototype* of a string. You can write `String.prototype.property = 'something'`, which will make all strings have a `property` property with the value of `something`. Including `'a'.property`.

Comment: @rdineiu Ah yes indeed, I use that all the time to do `'string'.contains('substring')`. However it seemed he wanted to do `'a'.prop=1; 'b'.prop=2; ...`; at least that was implied by the code. Nevertheless it's unfortunate that due to language and library issues, modifying Array.prototype and Object.prototype is dangerous, so those features get less use than they should.

Answer (score 0):

In js strings and simple types stored/returned by value, not by reference.

If in your array you have some object, then it will work.

Comment: While the issue does have to do with properties on `string` values, there is no "value" vs. "reference" distinction in JavaScript.

Comment: @pst, all except primitives are always by reference in JS. Primitives -- by value.

Comment: All values in in JavaScript are "by value" or "just themselves"; that is, a value of an object is itself -- *there is no reference*. (Implementations can use references *internally*; this detail is not leaked). All primitive values just happen to be *completely* immutable. *Java* introduces the distinction of "reference types"; JavaScript has no such distinction and the calling semantics are entirely described by [Call By Object Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) without needing to introduce "references" from different languages.

Comment: The [ECMA 262 ed 5 Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) does not talk about "references" in this sense (it does discuss the Reference Specification Type, but this is in relationship to name binding and evaluation of the operation `typeof`/`delete` and not "references to values").